# How to use python join the arrays and specify from which array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have 2 array:

```
Array_1=["apple","orange"]
Array_2=["kiwi"]
```

I wish to get the output as below:

```
"apple" 1
"orange" 1
"kiwi" 2
```

and this output will print in txt file, the 1 indicate from Array_1 and 2 indicate from Array_2.

Can anyone share me ideas?

Comment: Those are Python lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i, array in enumerate([Array_1, Array_2]):
        for s in array:
            print(f'"{s}"', i, file=f)
```

Where `'foo.txt'` is the path to your text file.

Comment: Hi i get the out put is in single quote for example 'apple' 1
Any way to make it as double quote for example "apple" 1